# Как сделать сортировку свойств в классе?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, классы, order, intellisense

Есть класс `DB`. Через `intellisense` отображение свойств идет по алфавиту, но хочется сделать чтобы я сам мог задавать ее.

```
class DB
{
    public string Url { get; set; } //2
    public string Category { get; set; } //1
}
```

Comment: нужно писать свое расширение для студии, если дело в ней происходит

Comment: *хочется сделать чтобы я сам мог задавать ее* - это Вы про порядок отображаемых свойств?

Comment: да, про порядок.

Comment: я правильно понял, что речь про `Visual Studio`?

Comment: да, все верно....

Comment: Не уверен насчет студии, решарпер вроде этот список перестраивает, последние использованные - сверху.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сортировка и фильтрация `Intellisense` списка в `Visual Studio` не предусматривает установку своего порядка отображения списка стандартными средствами. (На каком-то форуме натыкался на статью, где обсуждался данный функционал. Даже был запрос, на добавление такого функционала, но он не появился).

Для примера, для `Visual Studio` есть хороший инструментарий, плагин [`ReSharper`](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), который вносит полезные дополнения кода и помогает повысить продуктивность работы в `Visual Studio`. Но и в нем нет такой возможности.

Если у Вас имеются необходимые знания и опыт написания плагинов, то Вы можете написать плагин, подобный [`ReSharper`](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), который можно будет встроить в `Visual Studio` для индивидуального отображения `Intellisense` списка.